# Outer span width of bigger inner span?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the outer span the width of the longer inner span. C should be hidden until hover which will then make B hidden. If you look at the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JZJWM/) and click the button you'll see once B is longer than C it breaks. I could possibility server side check the string length and choose which should be the left side but that breaks depending on the string

lllllllll <-- 9 chars
wwww <-- 4 chars is wider

Source of demo

Html

```
Test
<span class="A">
    <span class="B">bbbb</span>
    <span class="C">CCCCCCCCC</span>
</span> Test
<button class="btn">Make B bigger</button>
```

CSS:

```
.A {
    border: black dotted 1px;
}
.B {
    position:absolute
}
.C {
    visibility:hidden
}
.A:Hover .B {
    visibility:hidden
}
.A:Hover .C {
    visibility:visible
}
```

JS:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $(".B").html("LONG WORD HERE");
});
```

Comment: I know you got solution. just have a look at this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/JZJWM/14/).

Comment: @Mr_Green: Thats a JS cheat. I won't know if in fact B is longer then C since its user input and the example with l's and w show I cant use str length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My previous solution was mistaken.
This one is better:

http://jsfiddle.net/JZJWM/10/

The only disadvantage is that you have to give B and C a fixed `height`. It can be probably improved but you can work on it by yourself.

Comment: This will be good, after you add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.A`.

Comment: Please also add the code here, the fiddle is not eternal and may stop working at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution using jQuery to manipulate the widths.

Alot of stuff is changed.

New CSS:

```
.A {
    display: inline-block;
    border: black dotted 1px;
}

.B, .C { position:absolute; }

.C { visibility:hidden }

.A:Hover .B { visibility:hidden }
.A:Hover .C { visibility:visible }
```

New HTML (note the `&nbsp;` - it stretches A vertically)

```
<span class="A"><span class="B">bbbb</span><span class="C">CCCCCCCCC</span>&nbsp;</span>
```

And finally the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".A").css("width", Math.max($(".B").outerWidth(), $(".C").outerWidth()));
});

$(".btn").click(function () {
    $(".B").html("LONG WORD HERE");
    $(".A").css("width", Math.max($(".B").outerWidth(), $(".C").outerWidth()));
});
```

Here's it all in **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MightyPork/JZJWM/9/)**.

Comment: Excellent. I may accept this. I might be forced to do this within CSS but I'm going to try and do it this way. Good answer.